# Marriage ceremony

Tags: word-choice, phrases, idioms

During a marriage ceremony, a priest pronounces a couple "man and wife”. This is preceded by a particular ritual through which the priest says some verses from the holy book and sometimes requires the couple to repeat the same after him. What is this last stage called? Can I say “**the marriage formula was pronounced?”**

Comment: The marriage vows were exchanged.

Comment: That's called different things in different religions.  If you're asking specifically about the part where the parties say "I do" or "I will" to questions along the lines of "do you take this man/woman to be your lawfully wedded spouse," that's generally called "exchange of consent."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There are many different wedding ceremonies in many different traditions (most of which, in the English-speaking world, would arguably not be performed by a "priest"), and many do not involve the couple repeating words from a holy book, particularly nowadays. Please [edit] the post to provide a specific example of the section you are talking about, especially as ecclesiastic terms (e.g. *reception of consent*, *rite of arras*, etc.) will not necessarily be recognized by lay people, even those from the same religious tradition as the couple.

Comment: As already said, there are numerous ceremonies. The most common terminology is simply *marriage vows*. (And even with that, some marriages are just civil events—not even necessarily ceremonies in the traditional sense of the word—that require nothing more than signatures. In which case, not even vows are exchanged.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional formula in English, whether it's a religious or secular ceremony, is

> The [person officiating the ceremony] pronounced the happy couple man and wife.

If you want something shorter and more abstract:

> The marriage ceremony was concluded.

Shortest: the [internet has shown me](https://hvcsampleceremonies.wordpress.com/ceremony-parts/conclusion-pronouncement/) that this phase of the proceeding is called the

**pronouncement**